# How to find the index of next matching element in list using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

i have a list say :

```
List<string> list = new List<string>(){"Oracle","SQL Server","Java","Oracle","Python"};
```

Now i'm trying to get index of the second "Oracle" from the list using LINQ:

```
var indexFirefox = list.FindIndex(a => a.Text == "Oracle");
```

But this will give you only the first instance that is index 0. I want index as 4 in my result. Will using Skip help or there is a more simplistic way of getting the index. The example above is just a demo, i have a list with over 300 values.

Comment: You can [pass a starting index](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/efasdh0s.aspx) to `FindIndex`. So you could find the first index, then find the next one by passing `index+1`.

Comment: I have many such occurances of matching elements so getting the previous index and then searching for the next one might just help. Let me try this. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So many Linq answer when there already exists one method doing the job (given in the first comment)

`List<T>.FindIndex` has an [overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/efasdh0s(v=vs.110).aspx) which takes an additional index parameter to search only from that index.

So to get the second occurrence of an item you just have to use that overload with the result of a "regular" `FindIndex`.
*(Note: in your question's sample you used `a.Text` but items are string so there is no Text property)*

```
var firstIndex = list.FindIndex (item => item == "Oracle");
if (firstIndex != -1)
{
    var secondIndex = list.FindIndex (firstIndex, item => item == "Oracle");
    // use secondIndex (can be -1 if there is no second occurrence)
}
```

And with your sample example `secondIndex` will be `3` *(and not 4 as stated in your question, indexes are zero-based)*

Alternatively if you want to get occurrence indexes in turn you can loop using that same method.

```
// defined here to not have to repeat it 
Predicate<string> match = item => item == "Oracle";

for (var index = list.FindIndex (match); index > -1; index = list.FindIndex (index + 1, match))
{
    // use index here
}
```

Or if you prefer a while loop

```
var index = list.FindIndex (match);

while (index > -1)
{
    // use index here

    index = list.FindeIndex (index + 1, match);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list.Where(x => x == "Oracle").ElementAt(1);
```

- Will crash if ther is no second find , you can just check the size of the enumerable before returning second element.

Comment: Checking the size of enumerable first entails multiple enumerations, this will not be the most efficient method. It's probably better to just `catch` in this case, or use a different method that won't throw.

Answer (score 0):

here i find index of next of matching element

```
list.Select((value, index) => new { value, index = index + 1 }).Where(x => x.value == "Oracle").Skip(1).FirstOrDefault().index
```

Answer (score 0):

This does it nicely for me:

```
var result =
    list
        .Select((x, n) => new { x, n })
        .Where(xn => xn.x == "Oracle")
        .Select(xn => xn.n)
        .Skip(1)
        .FirstOrDefault();
```

This gives `3` given the input `List<string> list = new List<string>(){"Oracle","SQL Server","Java","Oracle","Python"};`.